# Create a menu/options when the settings/menu button is pressed on the physical phone

Tags: java, android, menu, settings

I have the standard code as it is for a menu:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And what I want to do is have 2 options:
1 for settings 
1 for about us

If you could please help me code this, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create activity_main.xml in your /res/menu dir.  It would look something like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings_icon" />
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About"
        android:icon="@drawable/about_icon" />
</menu>
```

Note that you should also include icon resources settings_icon.png and about_icon.png in your /res/drawable dir.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_account, menu);
    return true;
}
```